# Usage of "entice" -- can the object be an abstract noun?

Tags: word-usage

We can say "the salesperson enticed the customer to buy something."  Can we also say "the salesperson enticed the customer's purchase"?  If not, what did the salesperson do to the purchase?  ("Elicit" can be used this way, but it doesn't have the same connotation as "entice" -- that the salesperson caused the customer to *want* to buy something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not idiomatic to say that a *purchase* was enticed. Consider saying that the sales person *induced* the purchase.

> **induce** *verb*
>   2 Bring about or give rise to.
>   ‘none of these measures induced a change of policy’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/induce)

Here are some examples from the internet (emphasis, mine):

- Another factor to be considered is the level of cash rebate which can **induce a purchase** from a customer.
  [- A Practical Approach to Marketing Management](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=DnYQx-Ks2dcC&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=%22induce%20a%20purchase%22&source=bl&ots=KeJhX-ZpYe&sig=YAgynrzWBqjfVALQSCY5-huOVc8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5wN2d3PfZAhUHQLwKHdRlDjkQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22induce%20a%20purchase%22&f=false) by Kujnish Vashisht
- The objective of a sales letter is threefold: ... 3. **Induce a purchase**
  [- Sales Letters, The Writing Studio](https://writing.colostate.edu/guides/page.cfm?pageid=1471&guideid=71)
- These unprotected beings are importuned in the streets by some emissary of a lottery office, and if persuasion be insufficient to **induce a purchase**, the tickets are sometimes thrust upon them.
  [- A brief survey of the great extent and evil tendencies of the lottery system](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=8yVKAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=%22induce%20a%20purchase%22&source=bl&ots=88b27Dh5Kj&sig=Z1PVTg69OmwUn5yfM8xYzQW9Z6A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5wN2d3PfZAhUHQLwKHdRlDjkQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=%22induce%20a%20purchase%22&f=false) by Job Roberts Tyson

Answer (score 0):

The verb "solicit" can be used in this sense, but beware it also can mean a very specific sort of approach to a customer: "Accost someone and offer one's or someone else's services as a prostitute."(Oxford Living Dictionaries)

Answer (score -1):

An *[enticement](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/enticement)* entices the customer to buy something.

> **enticement**, *n.*: [countable] an advantage or reward that persuades you to do something
>
> **enticement**, *n.*: [uncountable]  the process of enticing someone

So you can say, "the salesperson offered *an enticement* to secure the purchase."